# MDX code - Aggregate with Lag function not working

Tags: aggregate, mdx, lag

I'm trying to use the aggregate function but its returning like sum function, not sure what im doing wrong here. Ive tried to find a few examples online but nothing yet.

```
        WITH 
         MEMBER [Measures].[StartDate] AS
            Aggregate(@{Date!∅}.Lag(0), [Measures].[Net Sales])
         MEMBER [Measures].[7 Days] AS
            Aggregate(@{Date!∅}.Lag(7), [Measures].[Net Sales])
         MEMBER [Measures].[14 Days] AS
            Aggregate(@{Date!∅}.Lag(14), [Measures].[Net Sales])
         MEMBER [Measures].[21 Days] AS
            Aggregate(@{Date!∅}.Lag(21), [Measures].[Net Sales])
         MEMBER [Measures].[Avg 6-Mth Day] AS  
            (
               [Measures].[StartDate] + [Measures].[7 Days] + [Measures].[14 Days] + [Measures].[21 Days] 
            ) / 4
        
        SELECT
         NON EMPTY {      
            [Measures].[StartDate]
          , [Measures].[7 Days]
          , [Measures].[14 Days]
          , [Measures].[21 Days] 
         } ON "Columns"
         NON EMPTY [Calendar].[Hour].[Hour] ON "Rows"
        FROM 
         [ECRS Data Warehouse]
            WHERE 
             (@{Date!∅})
```

Expecting to get aggregate data by hour and not summed data by hour, its like its defaulting to sum not aggregate.